# Need help to write py code for my excel formula

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe, excel-formula

Every week I receive file from supplier which needs to be added in the summary file. I'm trying to automate this summary excel task using python.

I have a table in that there are Key column which contains shipping order id.
And other columns are of Week2 to currently Week32. And they contains day difference counts.
My last column is of Lead Time.
**So what these lead time does is it takes out the last non-zero cell of the row.
**
[image: Example for Lead Time]

Now I need help with coding for this Lead Time.

The code should apply for all the rows.

I'm not providing Excel formula as it is over complex and you can easily understand what the Lead Time column does using my definition and photo.

This is the code I applied using help of the ChatGPT. It doesn't work for all rows.

```
# Lead Time - if first and last cells are blank, it gives max value between the two cells. If last cell isnt blank, it gives the last cell

# new_week is variable name in this case it is equal to Week33
df_daydiff[new_week] = df_daydiff[new_week].astype(float)
#week_columns contains list of all column names starting with word Week
week_columns = df_daydiff.columns[df_daydiff.columns.str.startswith('Week')]

def calculate_lead_time(row):
    first_cell = row.iloc[0]
    last_cell = row.iloc[-1]
    week_values = row.iloc[1:-1]

    if pd.isnull(first_cell) and pd.isnull(last_cell):
        return week_values.dropna().max()
    elif pd.notnull(last_cell):
        return last_cell
    elif pd.notnull(first_cell) and pd.isnull(last_cell):
        return row[row.last_valid_index()]
    else:
        return np.nan

df_daydiff['Lead Time'] = df_daydiff[week_columns].apply(calculate_lead_time, axis=1)
```

I would like if you just ignore the code above and use your own logic here as it is taken from the GPT.

Comment: It would probably help to answer this question if you did provide the excel formula

Comment: Admitting you used chatGPT will cause only a lot of insults on this forum, from what I've seen, but apart from that my question is:
What do you mean by "doesn't work for all rows"? Please post what's the actual output and what is your expected output for the same example.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by you tagging excel-formula, and asking not to use an excel formula; not even posting your working version (even if it may be inefficient).
Instead you post a code chat GPT made for you that doesn't work and you don't even bother explaining what it does versus what you expect.

What I expect is that if lead time was 126 in week 3 and we are not in week 3, then leadtime changed, so the screenshot - to my understanding of what you may want to get returned as info is not showing the correct values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for an [excel-formula](/questions/tagged/excel-formula), you can use the one in <kbd>G2</kbd> and drag it all the way down :

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B2:F2,MATCH(2,1/(B2:F2<>""),1)),0)
```

The [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) equivalent would be something like below :

```
df_daydiff = pd.read_excel("file.xlsx")
weeks = df_daydiff.filter(like="Week") # or any equivalent
df_daydiff["Lead Time"] = weeks.ffill(axis=1).iloc[:, -1].fillna(0)
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: Thanks this is the answer I was searching for.

Answer (score 1):

if data in b2:f2
formula:

```
=ifna(LOOKUP(1,0/B2:F2,B2:F2),0)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.